# How do I set the padding of a ListView in code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-listview

I want to move what I have in my XML:

```
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
```

to my code:

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setPadding(12, 0, 12, 0);
```

The problem is that is appears the "setPadding" call only sets it by pixels, not dp. Anyone know how to properly set this in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to do the conversion manually:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
int sizeInPx = (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

dp is just dpi/160.

try this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
float dp = dm.densityDpi / 160;

listView.setPadding(12*dp, 0, 12*dp, 0);
```